# How to change rigs spine rotation in unity3d, using camera rotation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have a rigged 3d model of a person with animations that i made. It is a player model in a first person shooter. I want this model to "bow", when looking down or do the opposite, when looking up. To achieve this, i decided, instead of making an animation for each degree the player might decide looking at, to rotate models spine, depending on the angle of the camera. In scene view, i can easily change rotation value and get the results i want, however, when game is running, those parameters seem to be "locked" and no matter what script i tried, i cant seem to change the rotation value. I figured, perhaps, when animation is playing, i cant change things it effects, so made a body mask to excluded torso from animations and spines rotation was still locked away from me. Is there a way to rotate models spine, when its doing its normal, lets say, idle, animation? is there actually another easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update in LateUpdate(). Unity's animator does it's changes to the transform in Update(). By doing it in LateUpdate() it will be handled after the animation has made it's changes.